# If null/not null for date

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, null

Is there a way to deal with null or not null value from textbox?

```
 DateTime fdate = DateTime.Parse(Txtvalidade.Text);
       
 objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALIDADE", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtvalidade.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : fdate);
 DateTime fdate2 = DateTime.Parse(Txtrecebido.Text);           
 objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RECEBIMENTO", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtrecebido.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : fdate2);
```

My problem is if I let both txtvalidade/recebido null it raises a error on insert, if I insert dates it works fine.

Comment: Use what you have already in `AddWithValue`, just substitute `fdate` with `DateTime.Parse(Txtvalidade.Text)`. Do something similar with `fdate2`.

Comment: Something like: `objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALIDADE", DateTime.TryParse(Txtvalidade.Text, out fdate)) ? fdate : DBNull.Value);`

Comment: Consider using an ORM, like Dapper. This would force you to separate the logic of parsing user input and saving data to your RDBMS, which is better for your overall application structure anyway.

Comment: When is Textbox.Text ever null? If you want dates, use a DateTimePicker; you can type into it, but it doesn't accept garbage input like a textbox would

Comment: both raises error

Comment: because there're products that doen't have expiration date so it must be nullable info on database

Comment: The text in a text box is never null.  It may be empty, or it may have "Hello World" in it (which won't parse as a date), but it will never be null.  Consider using `TryParse` rather than `Parse`) to test the date-ed-ness of the text